# Why comes xpath to a different result than css with Selenium-WebElement (Python 3)

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

**Update1:**

Long question in short

I want the caption of each note on my google keep page.

When I finally search them with xpath, it gives me no result, but it works with css

I want to know why.

What I do

1. To keep the code short, I saved the google keep page to hdd and load it in the driver
2. Search for the notes in html code and get a list of them in Parent_Liste
3. show the outerHTML of each in Parent_Liste to be sure, that the caption is in the HTML-code
4. search for each caption in Parent_Liste search with xpath
5. search for each caption in Parent_Liste search with css

Below is the code and the output of the python console for the first element.
The first element has the caption: stackoverflowCaption

```
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome()

#step 1
driver.get("file://d:/google notizen.html") #on hdd saved google keep page

#step 2
Parent_Liste = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class,'IZ65Hb-n0tgWb IZ')]//div[@aria-label='Titel']/parent::*")

print("Number of Elements in Parent_Liste: " + str(len(Parent_Liste)))
print("=========================\n")

counter = 0

for each in Parent_Liste:
    print("\nElement of Parent_Liste: " + str(counter) + "\n======================") #prettify the output

#step 3
    print('outerHTML each Parent:\n' + each.get_attribute('outerHTML')) #here I get the outerHTML of the each-parent only for demonstraition


#step 4
    TitelElementxpath = each.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@aria-label='Titel']")  #here I want the WebElement with the caption
    print("xpath Result: " + TitelElementxpath.get_attribute('outerHTML')) #outerHTML has not the caption in the code
    print("xpath Result.text: " + TitelElementxpath.text)     # .text is empty

#step 5
    TitelElementcss = each.find_element_by_css_selector("div[aria-label='Titel']") #here I want the WebElement with the caption
    print("css Result: " + TitelElementcss.get_attribute('outerHTML')) #outerHTML has the caption in the code
    print("css Result.text: " + TitelElementcss.text)         # .text has the caption

    counter = counter + 1
```

**Output in Pyhton-Console for the first element**

```
Number of Elements in Parent_Liste: 7
=========================


Element of Parent_Liste: 0
======================
outerHTML each Parent:

<div class="IZ65Hb-s2gQvd"><div role="button" class="Q0hgme-LgbsSe Q0hgme-Bz112c-LgbsSe IZ65Hb-nQ1Faf VIpgJd-LgbsSe" aria-label="Notiz anpinnen" aria-disabled="false" aria-pressed="false" style="user-select: none;" tabindex="0"></div><div class="IZ65Hb-nQ1Faf-cQwEuf"></div><div class="IZ65Hb-hYUzqc"><div class="IZ65Hb-HiaYvf-neVct"></div></div><div contenteditable="false" aria-multiline="true" role="textbox" aria-label="Titel" class="notranslate IZ65Hb-YPqjbf r4nke-YPqjbf" dir="ltr" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">stackoverflowCaption</div><div contenteditable="false" aria-multiline="true" role="textbox" aria-label="Notiz" class="notranslate IZ65Hb-YPqjbf h1U9Be-YPqjbf" dir="ltr" style="">stackoverflowNote</div><div class="IZ65Hb-jfdpUb xFQqWe"><div class="Q0hgme-XPtOyb YPIHXb-Hjleke-XPtOyb" style="display: none;"><div role="button" class="Q0hgme-LgbsSe XPtOyb-bN97Pc VIpgJd-LgbsSe" tabindex="0" style="user-select: none;"><div class="XPtOyb-Bz112c"></div><label class="XPtOyb-fmcmS"></label></div><div role="button" class="Q0hgme-LgbsSe Q0hgme-Bz112c-LgbsSe XPtOyb-VkLyEc VIpgJd-LgbsSe" tabindex="0" aria-label="Quelle entfernen" style="user-select: none;"></div></div><div class="Q0hgme-XPtOyb zyxPWd-XPtOyb" style="display: none;"><div role="button" class="Q0hgme-LgbsSe XPtOyb-bN97Pc VIpgJd-LgbsSe" tabindex="0" style="user-select: none;"><div class="XPtOyb-Bz112c"></div><label class="XPtOyb-fmcmS"></label></div><div role="button" class="Q0hgme-LgbsSe Q0hgme-Bz112c-LgbsSe XPtOyb-VkLyEc VIpgJd-LgbsSe" tabindex="0" aria-label="Erinnerung löschen" style="user-select: none;"></div></div><div class="IZ65Hb-jfdpUb-fmcmS" aria-label="Erstellt um 09:47">Bearbeitet: 09:47</div></div><div class="IZ65Hb-kODWGd" style="display: none;"></div></div>
xpath Result: <div contenteditable="true" aria-multiline="true" role="textbox" aria-label="Titel" class="notranslate IZ65Hb-YPqjbf r4nke-YPqjbf" style="display: none; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" tabindex="0"></div>
xpath Result.text: 
css Result: <div contenteditable="false" aria-multiline="true" role="textbox" aria-label="Titel" class="notranslate IZ65Hb-YPqjbf r4nke-YPqjbf" dir="ltr" style="background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);">stackoverflowCaption</div>
css Result.text: stackoverflowCaption
```

Comment: Can you post the source? hard to say otherwise

Comment: If we aren't logged into your google account, we can't see what you are seeing. You need to post the relevant HTML. Also shorten your description... it's too long and difficult to follow. I don't believe the XPath you are using for `Titel_Liste` is correct because `'IZ65Hb-n0tgWb IZ'` doesn't match the classnames of the elements you posted.